# SignalR in service worker

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, push-notification, signalr, service-worker

Is it possible to use SignalR instead of firebase to send notification in Service Worker?
so that the notification can be shown if the user's browser is closed.
Thank you for helping me with my code.
My project is with Nuxt.js v2

```
let ministry_server = "ip/notifHub";
let connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(ministry_server, {
    accessTokenFactory: () => "token"
}).withAutomaticReconnect([0, 1000, 5000, null]).build();

connection.start();

connection.on("get", function (res) {
    Notification.requestPermission((result) => {
        if (result === 'granted') {
            console.log(res)
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
                registration.showNotification('Vibration Sample', {
                    body: res,
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```